# Rails: Adding custom validation method to validate password for user model only on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, passwords

I need to add custom validation only on action :update for my user model. Users are created only with email, so when they update password is set. I want to add validations on update for password.

```
validate :custom_validation, on: :update

#storing password
def password=(password_str)
  @password = password_str 
  self.password_salt   = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
  self.password_digest = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password_str, password_salt)
end

def custom_validation

  if !(self.password.present? || self.password_confirmation.present?)
   errors.add(:password, 'password and password_confirmation can\'t be blank')
 end

if self.password.present? && self.password.length < 6
  errors.add(:password, 'password length should be greater than 6')
end
```

end
Does not validate my user password.....

Comment: What is not working? Is your password updating without the proper format, or do you not get an error message or what?

Comment: in the table, password and password_confirmation is saved as it is.

Comment: when custom_validation method is called, it checks for the values of password which is already saved inthe table, not for the ones i send in the form.